# Regex to fit pattern of percentages with 4 decimals?

Tags: regex

Hi I'm looking for a regular expression that would match only numbers that represent percentages with up to 4 decimals. meaning for example:

| should match | should not match |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 100.0001 |
| 99.9999 | 101 |
| 0.0001 | 100.00001 |
| 0 |  |

Iv'e tried this but it does not work (does not match 0.0004 for example):

```
"^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,4}$"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `100.0000`?

Answer (score 0):

Use alterations to capture the different possibilities.

This works:

```
^((?:100)|(?:100\.0{1,4})|(?:\d{1,2})|(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,4}))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iIWXkD/2)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to aproach this is by considering 100% to be a special case.

```
^(100(\.0{1,4})?|\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,4})?)$
```

That way you can match 0->99.9999 or 100 with up to 4 decimal 0s after it.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AF4LkI/1)